# Can't change Font Awesome color with CSS

Tags: css

I have been trying to change the glyph colors from Font Awesome to green, but not matter what I do, I can't get it to change the color. All I can manage is change the background color, but the glyph stays the same gray color. I have tried looking it up online, and everyone says just add color to the icon like so:

```
    .fa-check-circle .green{
  color: #24ff30;
}


<i className="far fa-check-circle fa-2x green"></i>
```

But this is what it looks like when I do that:

[image]

I want the background to be clear and the icon itself to be that green color, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: which version ?

Comment: where are you setting background-color green?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that your selector is right?
`.fa-check-circle .green` selects the element `.green` in the parent `.fa-check-circle`.

I think in your case it should be

```
.fa-check-circle.green
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the space between `.fa-check-circle` and `.green` class.

Answer (score 0):

Check your selector is correct. Also check that your css files are in the correct order and that you don't have any conflicting styles between other elements. If all else fails try specifying !important or setting an inline style.